# Xsession errors - cannot log in

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm running linux mint 14 and when I try to log in I get an error saying "Session lasted less than 10 seconds...". When I click on details it says:

```
/etc/mdm/Xsession: Beginning session setup...
/etc/mdm/Xsession: 1: /etc/profile: id: not found
/etc/mdm/Xsession: 12: [: Illegal number:
/etc/mdm/Xsession: 173: /etc/mdm/Xsession: grep: not found
/etc/mdm/Xsession: Executing default failed, will try to run x-terminal-emulator
/etc/mdm/Xsession: 205: exec: x-terminal-emulator: not found
```

I edited the /etc/environment file so maybe that has something to do with it.

I restarted in recovery mode and selected "Drop to root shell prompt". I attempted to edit the /etc/environment file, but it says it's read only (even while using sudo).

What can i do?

Comment: What changes did you make to that file? That error seems to be complaining about something in /etc/profile and /etc/mdm/Xsession. And seems to be complaining about a bunch of missing commands that really should exist. In recovery mode your disk is probably in read-only mode. You probably just need to remount it read-write.

Comment: i was installing Ant and changed contents of environment file to: ANT_HOME=/apache-install-dir/apache-ant-version
ANT_OPTS="-Xms256M -Xmx512M"
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$ANT_HOME/bin
export ANT_HOME ANT_OPTS PATH

Comment: how do i remount in read-write?

Comment: `mount -o remount,rw /` or so.

Comment: I don't think `/etc/environment` wants the export line.

Comment: i cant seem to remount in read-write, it says cant find rw in /etc/mtab

Comment: What command did you use exactly?

Comment: @user1716672 no spaces in `remount,rw`

Comment: wonderful, i can modify now

Comment: i removed the export line but still getting same error. what is the default contents of /etc/environment file?

Comment: i deleted everything in the file and replaced with PATH=/usr/bin, which worked. Thanks for help.

Comment: You want at least ``/bin:/usr/bin`` there. Which should be the default, so do not set any path there. As ant is a commandline tool, use .bash_profile (or other shell configuration file). And try a new terminal BEFORE closing the old one to avoid having the same problem with the shell configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

I mounted with read-write privileges with:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

And changed contents of environment file back to:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
```

This solved the problem.

Comment: If you learn nothing else from this exercise, hopefully it will teach you to make a copy of any system file before changing it.  It makes backing out your changes **much** easier afterwards!